# How to identify cut and paste of page in Tridion

Tags: web8

Is there any way to identify the cut of a page from one structure group to other in Tridion

Comment: There is an event triggered for pasting of items - is this what you're looking for? What do you need to achieve on this?

Answer (score 4):

You know, this is asked rather generic, so I'll answer in that way as well. Please add more detail as to what you're trying to achieve and we'll be able to answer better.

> Is there any way to identify the cut of a page from one structure group to other in Tridion?

Yes. Look at Page / MoveEventArgs or CopyEventArgs in Event system.

Answer (score 0):

Please try sample code MoveEventArgs/CopyEventArgs.

Here is the code of the subscriptions. As said above, all other events are fired. Just not the move and copy ones.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Justitie.Tcm.EventHandlers.EventTypes;
using Justitie.Tcm.EventHandlers.HelperClasses;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events;

namespace Justitie.Tcm.EventHandlers
{
[TcmExtension("EventsHandler")]
public class EventsHandler : TcmExtension, IDisposable
{
    EventSubscription _subscription;
    private JustitieEvents eventSystem = null;
    private string exeConfigPath;
    private Configuration config;

    public EventsHandler()
    {
        exeConfigPath = this.GetType().Assembly.Location;
        try
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.ERROR, "No Config file could be found. Errmsg: " + ex.Message);
        }

        Subscribe();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        //Component save events
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForComponentPreSave, EventPhases.Initiated);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForComponentPostSave, EventPhases.Processed);

        //Component Delete events
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, DeleteEventArgs>(HandlerForComponentPreDelete, EventPhases.Initiated);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, DeleteEventArgs>(HandlerForComponentPostDelete, EventPhases.Processed);

        //Component Publish Events
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, PublishEventArgs>(HandlerForComponentPrePublish, EventPhases.Initiated);

        //Page save events
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SaveEventArgs>(HandlerForPagePreSave, EventPhases.Initiated);

        //Page Publish Events
        /*_subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, SetPublishStateEventArgs>(HandlerForPageSetToPublish, EventPhases.Processed);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(HandlerForPagePrePublish, EventPhases.Initiated);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(HandlerForPagePostPublish, EventPhases.Processed);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, UnPublishEventArgs>(HandlerForPagePostUnPublish, EventPhases.Processed);*/

        //Folder PasteItem Events
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Folder, MoveEventArgs>(HandlerForFolderPostCutPaste, EventPhases.Processed);
        _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<Folder, CopyEventArgs>(HandlerForFolderPostCopyPaste, EventPhases.Processed);

    }

    private void HandlerForComponentPreSave(Component subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnComponentSaveInitiatedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config));
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.ComponentSavePre(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForComponentPostSave(Component subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnComponentSaveCommittedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config));
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.ComponentSavePost(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForComponentPreDelete(Component subject, DeleteEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnComponentDeleteInitiatedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config));
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.ComponentPreDelete(subject);
    }

    private void HandlerForComponentPostDelete(Component subject, DeleteEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnComponentDeleteCommittedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config));
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.ComponentPostDelete(subject);
    }

    private void HandlerForComponentPrePublish(Component subject, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnComponentPublishInitiatedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config));
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.ComponentPrePublish(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForPagePreSave(Page subject, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called PageSavePre " + phase.ToString() + " on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.PageSavePre(subject, args);
    }


    private void HandlerForPageSetToPublish(Page subject, SetPublishStateEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called PageSetToPublish " + phase.ToString() + " on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.PageSetPublishedToPost(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForPagePrePublish(Page subject, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called PagePrePublish " + phase.ToString() + " on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.PagePrePublish(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForPagePostPublish(Page subject, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called PagePostPublish " + phase.ToString() + " on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.PagePostPublish(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForPagePostUnPublish(Page subject, UnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called PagePostUnPublish " + phase.ToString() + " on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.PagePostUnPublish(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForFolderPostCutPaste(Folder subject, MoveEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnFolderPasteItemCommittedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.FolderPostCutPasteItem(subject, args);
    }

    private void HandlerForFolderPostCopyPaste(Folder subject, CopyEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        Logger.WriteLog(LogLevelL4N.DEBUG, "Called OnFolderPasteItemCommittedEvent on Events: " + Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString());
        Utilities.LoadEventSystem(exeConfigPath, Utilities.GetPubEventSystem(subject.OwningRepository.Title, config).ToString(), subject.Session, ref eventSystem);
        eventSystem.FolderPostCopyPasteItem(subject, args);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```